# How can I vertical align text at top of div?

Tags: html, css

How to align the `<span>` text at top of the `<div>` if `float:right` is applied to the `<span>`.

Here is my code:

```css
span {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
  <br>consectetuer adipiscing elit,
  <br> sed diam nonummy nibh dolore
  <span>Align me</span>
</div>
```

I tried `vertical-align:text-top` but its not working.
I can't use negative margin and can't even make any changes to HTML.

Comment: Where is the div in your code?

Comment: position: relative and bottom: <adjust according to requirement>

Comment: It's not going to work in the way you intend, since you are floating the element in question - but since you are doing that, can't you place it before any text? `<p><span>Align me</span>All the other text follows...</p>`

Comment: I'd say it's impossible to find a solid solution working with any length of text. If you could just move the span to the beginning of the div, everything would work as it is. With pure CSS it's not possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please [see](https://jsfiddle.net/x8rk9sL5/) this and let me know.

```
span {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  bottom:40px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can align it to the top right using `position: absolute`:

```css
 p {
  position: relative;
 }

span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <br>consectetuer adipiscing elit,<br> sed diam nonummy nibh dolore <span>Align me</span></p>
```

Comment: But that will mean content will no longer flow around it, since it is not floated.

Comment: @Terry - indeed, but it doesn't seem to be the problem in his example.

Comment: Positioning will remove the float property which will be a problem in my situation

Answer (score 3):

You can use Flexbox and set `align-items: flex-start`.

```css
p {
   display: flex;
   align-items: flex-start;
   justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <br>consectetuer adipiscing elit,<br> sed diam nonummy nibh dolore <span>Align me</span></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

[here is the example](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_vertical-align&preval=middle)since you cannot edit the `HTML`you can make a `css` change 
example:

```
    span#mySpan {
    background-color:yellow;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think **position:absolute** is best now. 

Like, 
`position:absolute;
right:0;
top:0;}`
 just try

Answer (score 0):

#### Translating  :

```
span {
  float: right;
  transform:translateY(-200%)
}
```

#### CSS grid  :

```
p {
  display: grid;
}

span {
  float: right;
  grid-column-start:2;
  text-align: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you to solve your problem:

```
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
  <br>consectetuer adipiscing elit,
  <br> sed diam nonummy nibh dolore
  <span>Align me</span>
</div>


div {  
   border: 1px solid gray;
   position: relative; 
   display: flex;
    }

span {
  display: inline-block;     
}
```